# Scriptella - dynamically name csv file

Tags: csv, scriptella

I would like to create a csv file with a value I get during executing the etl script. E.g. I get a new value from a sequence and want to append it to the name of the csv. Sounds simple, but I'm really stuck...

My script:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>Scriptella ETL</description>
    <properties>
        <include href="etl.properties"/> <!--Load from external properties file-->
    </properties>
    <!-- Connection declarations -->
    <connection id="mypostgres" driver="$driver" url="$url" user="$user" password="$password" classpath="$classpath"/>
    <connection driver="jexl" id="jexl"/>
    <connection id="log" driver="text"/>

    <query connection-id="mypostgres">
        select nextval('transfer_id_seq') as tid
        <script connection-id="jexl">
            etl.globals['transferID'] = tid;
        </script>
        <script connection-id="log">
            TransferID: ${etl.globals['transferID']}
        </script>
    </query>

    <script connection-id="log">
        TransferID (Outside query): ${etl.globals['transferID']}
    </script>

    <connection id="transfer-csv" driver="csv" url="transfer_${etl.globals['transferID']}.csv">
        null_string=
        quote=
    </connection>

    <script connection-id="transfer-csv">
        col1, col2, col3
    </script>
</etl>
```

My output:

```
C:\scriptella>scriptella
C:\java\jdk1.8\bin\java.exe -cp ;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\commons-compiler-jdk.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\commons-compiler.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\commons-jexl.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.
1\lib\commons-logging.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\janino.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\scriptella-core.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\scriptella-drivers.jar;C:\dev\scriptella-1.1\lib\scriptella-tools
.jar scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <WARNING> XML configuration warning in file:/C:/scriptella/etl.xml(35:7): The content of element type "etl" must match "(description?,properties?,connection*,(script*,
query*)*)".
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initializing properties: 1%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=mypostgres, JdbcConnection{org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection}, Dialect{PostgreSQL 9.3.2}, properties {}: 2%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=jexl, JexlConnection, Dialect{JEXL 2.0}, properties {}: 3%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=log, TextConnection, Dialect{Text 1.0}, properties {}: 4%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=transfer-csv, CsvConnection, Dialect{CSV 1.0}, properties {null_string=, quote=}: 5%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/query[1] prepared: 6%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/script[1] prepared: 7%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/script[2] prepared: 10%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Registered JMX mbean: scriptella:type=etl,url="file:/C:/scriptella/etl.xml"
TransferID: 171
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/query[1] executed: 38%
TransferID (Outside query): 171
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/script[1] executed: 66%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/script[2] executed: 95%
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Complete
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution statistics:
Executed 1 query, 4 scripts, 4 statements
/etl/query[1]: Element successfully executed (1 statement). Working time 11 milliseconds. Avg throughput: 89,63 statements/sec.
/etl/query[1]/script[1]: Element successfully executed. Working time 9 milliseconds.
/etl/query[1]/script[2]: Element successfully executed (1 statement). Working time 4 milliseconds. Avg throughput: 206,37 statements/sec.
/etl/script[1]: Element successfully executed (1 statement). Working time 2 milliseconds. Avg throughput: 432,13 statements/sec.
/etl/script[2]: Element successfully executed (1 statement). Working time 2 milliseconds. Avg throughput: 447,04 statements/sec.
Total working time: 0,26 second
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Successfully executed ETL file C:\scriptella\etl.xml
```

As you see the csv filename is wrong:

```
Directory of C:\scriptella

23.02.2015  17:33    <DIR>          .
23.02.2015  17:33    <DIR>          ..
23.02.2015  11:28               282 etl.properties
23.02.2015  17:32             1.239 etl.xml
23.02.2015  17:33               133 transfer_transferID.csv
               3 File(s)          1.654 bytes
               2 Dir(s)     741.036.032 bytes free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have a dynamic connection element, as Scriptella processes all connections at startup (from your 5% log line):

```
23.02.2015 17:33:58 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=transfer-csv, CsvConnection, Dialect{CSV 1.0}, properties {null_string=, quote=}: 5%
```

The best option is to use the *scriptella* driver, which will allow you to call another etl.xml as a subroutine (and no need for globals, actually):

etl.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <description>Scriptella ETL</description>
    <properties>
        <include href="etl.properties"/> <!--Load from external properties file-->
    </properties>
    <!-- Connection declarations -->
    <connection id="mypostgres" driver="$driver" url="$url" user="$user" password="$password" classpath="$classpath"/>
    <connection id="log" driver="text"/>
    <connection id="scriptella" driver="scriptella"/>
    <query connection-id="mypostgres">
        select nextval('transfer_id_seq') as tid
        <script connection-id="log">
            TransferID: $tid
        </script>
        <script connection-id="scriptella">
            dynamic.xml
        </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```

dynamic.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <connection id="transfer-csv" driver="csv" url="transfer_${tid}.csv">
       null_string=
        quote=
    </connection>
    <script connection-id="transfer-csv">
        col1, col2, col3
    </script>
</etl>
```

**NOTE:** The ${var} syntax is required in the dynamic.xml file's connection url.

Also, there is no way to have scriptella append to a csv file (it will truncate each time), so I think what you are trying to accomplish might require a rethinking of your process. [The Scriptella FAQ on Working with CSV Data](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/reference/index.html#Working+with+CSV+and+text+data) suggests using HSQLDB text tables, which might help -- using HSQLDB or H2 to stage the data you need to export will probably be a performance gain and make your process more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Sean, thanks for your answer. Very creative. It looks like a good solution. Re rethinking my process... It resulted in not using scriptella anymore because it's very fiddly to make it work and also they stopped developing it. Groovy was my choice but another scripting tool would also work.

Answer (score 0):

In Scriptella 1.2 (I'm not sure if it is applicable to older Scriptella versions), you can set CSV file name dynamically like this:

```
<connection id="out" driver="csv" url="my_report_${date:today('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')}.csv">
```

As per: http://scriptella.org/reference/index.html#%3Cproperties%3E
See "Expressions and Variables Substitution".

BTW, Scriptella lacks more structured and convenient documentation.